# How do I add confidence intervals to odds ratios in stargazer table?

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to create a table of a multivariable logistic regression model using `stargazer`. I would like to include odds ratios **and their confidence intervals** instead of the model coefficients.

I figured out how to replace the coefficients with the odds ratios, thanks to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236560/odds-ratios-instead-of-logits-in-stargazer-latex-output) but doing the same with the CI creates problems. If I give `stargazer` an argument like `se = *a list of the standard errors or exp(standard errors)*` it calculates the CI using the OR +/- 1.96 times that list, which is incorrect.

Here's some sample code, first part from [UCLA DAE](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm):

```
library(stargazer)
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit) 

# Table with coefficients
stargazer(mylogit, ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")

# Table with Odds Ratios, but the CI is not right
OR.vector <- exp(mylogit$coef)
stargazer(mylogit, coef = list(OR.vector), ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")

# Correct CIs
CI.vector <- exp(confint(mylogit))
cbind(OR = OR.vector, CI.vector)
```

Comment: here is data file: stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ci.custom` argument to feed `stargazer` a list with custom confidence intervals (first column is the lower bound, second column is the upper bound). In your example, all you have to do is call:

```
stargazer(mylogit, coef = list(OR.vector), ci = T, 
ci.custom = list(CI.vector), single.row = T, type = "text")
```

Alternatively, you can define your own function to exponentiate values and simply apply this function to your coefficients and/or confidence intervals (using arguments `apply.coef` and `apply.ci`):

```
exponentiate <- function(x) exp(x)

stargazer(mylogit, ci=T, apply.coef=exponentiate, apply.ci=exponentiate, 
single.row = T, type="text")
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using an old version of `stargazer` so I missed the `ci.custom` argument. If I might ask one more formatting question--in the output using `ci.custom`, the "stars" are not the same as for the standard output. That is, some "significant" results are not being starred. I looked at the star arguments but they don't seem to address this issue. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can use the `p` argument to specify custom p-values. Decisions about statistical significance stars are made based on these values. (In their absence, the significance stars will be calculated from the available - implicitly or explicitly - coefficients and standard errors.) Please note that I have edited my answer to include an alternative way of achieving the same result using `apply.coef` and `apply.ci`.

Comment: That's superb! I added the example code to your answer. I really like calling the `exponentiate` helper but your code does not produce the same CIs for some reason. It produces the same CIs as `stargazer(mylogit, coef = list(OR.vector), ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")`

Comment: I wonder of @MC808 has solved this problem, but the `apply.ci=exponentiate` argument behaves very weirdly. I can't replicate their result by manually calculate `exp(confint(mylogit))`.

Comment: @Heisenberg and @Marek, `apply.ci` seems to behave strangely for me as well (whereas `apply.coef` seems to work). Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: here is data file: stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv

Answer (score 9):

Thank you to Marek for the assistance with this question. Here's the code that worked for me in this example:

```
library(stargazer)
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit) 

# Table with coefficients
stargazer(mylogit, ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")

OR.vector <- exp(mylogit$coef)
CI.vector <- exp(confint(mylogit))
p.values <- summary(mylogit)$coefficients[, 4]

# Table with ORs and CIs
stargazer(mylogit, coef = list(OR.vector), ci = T, 
          ci.custom = list(CI.vector), p = list(p.values), 
          single.row = T, type = "text")
```

Comment: This looks to be a solution for one model, but I am working with a table comparing 8 models. Can I manipulate stargazer to produce a table with many models, containing odds ratios and 95% CI of the odds ratios? My first guess, apply.ci=exp produces results where the odds ratio does not fall in the range of the CI output.  @Marek