# How to correctly get p-value stars with stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

This is my code that works as intended (originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576356/how-do-i-add-confidence-intervals-to-odds-ratios-in-stargazer-table?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
library(stargazer)
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit) 

# Table with coefficients
stargazer(mylogit, ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")

OR.vector <- exp(mylogit$coef)
CI.vector <- exp(confint(mylogit))
p.values <- summary(mylogit)$coefficients[, 4]

# Table with ORs and CIs
stargazer(mylogit, coef = list(OR.vector), ci = T, ci.custom = list(CI.vector), p = list(p.values), single.row = T, type = "text")
```

it gives correct output:

```
Call:
glm(formula = admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, family = "binomial", 
    data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6268  -0.8662  -0.6388   1.1490   2.0790  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.989979   1.139951  -3.500 0.000465 ***
gre          0.002264   0.001094   2.070 0.038465 *  
gpa          0.804038   0.331819   2.423 0.015388 *  
rank2       -0.675443   0.316490  -2.134 0.032829 *  
rank3       -1.340204   0.345306  -3.881 0.000104 ***
rank4       -1.551464   0.417832  -3.713 0.000205 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 499.98  on 399  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 458.52  on 394  degrees of freedom
AIC: 470.52

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> 
> # Table with coefficients
> stargazer(mylogit, ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")

=============================================
                      Dependent variable:    
                  ---------------------------
                             admit           
---------------------------------------------
gre                 0.002** (0.0001, 0.004)  
gpa                 0.804** (0.154, 1.454)   
rank2              -0.675** (-1.296, -0.055) 
rank3             -1.340*** (-2.017, -0.663) 
rank4             -1.551*** (-2.370, -0.733) 
Constant          -3.990*** (-6.224, -1.756) 
---------------------------------------------
Observations                  400            
Log Likelihood             -229.259          
Akaike Inf. Crit.           470.517          
=============================================
Note:             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
> 
> OR.vector <- exp(mylogit$coef)
> CI.vector <- exp(confint(mylogit))
Waiting for profiling to be done...
> p.values <- summary(mylogit)$coefficients[, 4]
> 
> # Table with ORs and CIs
> stargazer(mylogit, coef = list(OR.vector), ci = T, ci.custom = list(CI.vector), p = list(p.values), single.row = T, type = "text")

=============================================
                      Dependent variable:    
                  ---------------------------
                             admit           
---------------------------------------------
gre                 1.002** (1.000, 1.004)   
gpa                 2.235** (1.174, 4.324)   
rank2               0.509** (0.272, 0.945)   
rank3               0.262*** (0.132, 0.512)  
rank4               0.212*** (0.091, 0.471)  
Constant            0.019*** (0.002, 0.167)  
---------------------------------------------
Observations                  400            
Log Likelihood             -229.259          
Akaike Inf. Crit.           470.517          
=============================================
Note:             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Now I do not want to seperetly exponentiate estimates and CI and want to use stargazer like in below code:

```
stargazer(mylogit, apply.coef = exp, apply.ci = exp, ci = TRUE, ci.level = 0.95, single.row = T, type = "text")
```

but it gives me output with incorrect p-value stars:

```
=============================================
                      Dependent variable:    
                  ---------------------------
                             admit           
---------------------------------------------
gre                 1.002*** (2.719, 2.730)  
gpa                2.235*** (4.875, 17.902)  
rank2                0.509 (0.895, 3.093)    
rank3                0.262 (0.660, 2.556)    
rank4                0.212 (0.545, 2.804)    
Constant             0.019 (0.109, 9.514)    
---------------------------------------------
Observations                  400            
Log Likelihood             -229.259          
Akaike Inf. Crit.           470.517          
=============================================
Note: 

        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

**Question:** Why last line of code gives me error and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: speaking from experience, almost any hack is easier than debugging/fixing [stargazer code](https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/master/R/stargazer-internal.R)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty simple hack. I'm not sure how much variation there is in the patterns between the coefficients and confidence intervals, but this could be improved or generalized.

```
library('stargazer')
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit) 

# Table with coefficients
x <- stargazer(mylogit, ci = T, single.row = T, type = "text")
y <- stargazer(mylogit, apply.coef = exp, apply.ci = exp, ci = TRUE, ci.level = 0.95, single.row = T, type = "text")

f <- function(x, y) {
  ## make sure both objects are similar
  stopifnot(
    identical(
      gsub('^(\\S+)|.', '\\1', x),
      gsub('^(\\S+)|.', '\\1', y)
    )
  )
  ## where and what to get from x
  mx <- gregexpr('(?<=\\d)[*]+ (?=\\()', x, perl = TRUE)
  ## where and what to subtract from y
  my <- gregexpr('(?<=\\d)[*]* (?=\\()', y, perl = TRUE)
  regmatches(y, my) <- regmatches(x, mx)

  cat(y, sep = '\n')
  invisible(y)
}

f(x, y)

# =============================================
#                       Dependent variable:    
#                   ---------------------------
#                              admit           
# ---------------------------------------------
# gre                 1.002** (2.719, 2.730)  
# gpa                2.235** (4.875, 17.902)  
# rank2                0.509** (0.895, 3.093)    
# rank3                0.262*** (0.660, 2.556)    
# rank4                0.212*** (0.545, 2.804)    
# Constant             0.019*** (0.109, 9.514)    
# ---------------------------------------------
# Observations                  400            
# Log Likelihood             -229.259          
# Akaike Inf. Crit.           470.517          
# =============================================
# Note:             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```