# Stargazer for reporting odds ratios in logit report wrong significance stars

Tags: r, logistic-regression, stargazer

I am running a logistic regression and reporting the results with stargazer. I've noticed that when I apply the apply.coef = OR option (so that the odds ratios would be reported), the significance stars are reported wrongly - in some cases there is no stars instead of three, sometimes there are stars when there shouldn't be.
For example;

```
stargazer(basic.logit.model, 
      type="html",
      apply.coef = OR,
      column.labels = c("Base"),
      dep.var.labels.include = FALSE,
      digits=2, out=("basic_model_only.htm"))
```

yields

```
X   0.33
(0.23)
Constant    0.03
(0.11)
Observations    6,532
Log Likelihood  -552.64
Akaike Inf. Crit.   1,109.28
Note:   *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

and without the apply-coef option, the results are:

```
X  -1.10***
(0.23)
Constant    -3.68***
(0.11)
Observations    6,532
Log Likelihood  -552.64
Akaike Inf. Crit.   1,109.28
Note:   *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally you should strive to provide a minimal working example so we can reproduce your results - in this case it would be great to have data and the code you use to produce your `basic.logit.model`.

To your question, `apply.coef` only transforms your coefficients but not the standard errors as your results show. stargazer calculates the significance level using these untransformed SEs which results in non-significant coefficients.

To avoid this, provide stargazer with the custom p-values (those from the original model) using the `p` argument.

This should work for you

```
p.values <- list(summary(basic.logit.model)$coefficients[,4]

stargazer(basic.logit.model, 
  type="html",
  apply.coef = OR,
  p = p.values,
  column.labels = c("Base"),
  dep.var.labels.include = FALSE,
  digits=2, out=("basic_model_only.htm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, the t-stats would also be wrong:

Instead, it is much simpler to stargazer not to recalculate the t-stats and p-values as follows:

```
stargazer(basic.logit.model, apply.coef = exp, t.auto=F, p.auto=F)
```

Also, note that your Std Errors and Confidence Intervals will be wrong unless you adjust.

For CIs, its pretty simple:

```
stargazer(basic.logit.model, apply.coef = exp, apply.ci = exp, t.auto=F, p.auto=F, ci = T)
```

**If you want to report Std Errors, you cannot use the `apply.se = exp` option.**

See the following post for how to do it:
[Odds ratios instead of logits in stargazer() LaTeX output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236560/odds-ratios-instead-of-logits-in-stargazer-latex-output/63789273#63789273)

Comment: I tried using the approach you mention here. When I use `apply.coef = exp, apply.ci = exp` I get results that are clearly incorrect --- the CIs don't include the central estimate. When I tried just using `apply.coef = exp` and doing nothing to the CIs, I got CIs that looked about right, but comparing them to the CIs that `jtools::summ` produces, they are a bit too narrow. Any ideas what might be going on?