# how to report exp(coefs) of a coxph regression with stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer, cox-regression

Say I have `my.model`

```
My.model <- coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ (rx + size + number) * strata(enum),
      cluster = id, bladder1)
```

I would like to create a model report table which contains `exp(coefs)` instead of `coefs`

```
stargazer(my.model)
```

is there a parameter like `exponentiate = TRUE` which would report `exp(coefs)` instead of `coefs`?, or I need to transform the model results before passing to `stargazer()`?

Comment: I think the only way is tranforming the coefs first manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get exponentiated coeficients, need to add parameters `apply.coef = exp, p.auto = FALSE, t.auto = FALSE`.

```
My.model <- coxph(Surv(stop, event) ~ rx + size + number,
                  cluster = id, bladder)
```

Original Model untransformed coeffs

```
stargazer(My.model, align=TRUE, 
          type="text",  digits = 3)
================================================
                         Dependent variable:    
                     ---------------------------
                                stop            
------------------------------------------------
rx                             -0.540*          
                               (0.200)          
                                                
size                           -0.055           
                               (0.070)          
                                                
number                        0.193***          
                               (0.046)          
                                                
------------------------------------------------
Observations                     340            
R2                              0.064           
Max. Possible R2                0.971           
Log Likelihood                -588.104          
Wald Test                12.510*** (df = 3)     
LR Test                  22.321*** (df = 3)     
Score (Logrank) Test     25.183*** (df = 3)     
================================================
Note: se in parenthesis *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Use the parameter `apply.coef = exp` to exponentiate.

```
stargazer(My.model, align=TRUE, apply.coef = exp,
          type="text",  digits = 3)

================================================
                         Dependent variable:    
                     ---------------------------
                                stop            
------------------------------------------------
rx                            0.583***          
                               (0.200)          
                                                
size                          0.947***          
                               (0.070)          
                                                
number                        1.213***          
                               (0.046)          
                                                
------------------------------------------------
Observations                     340            
R2                              0.064           
Max. Possible R2                0.971           
Log Likelihood                -588.104          
Wald Test                12.510*** (df = 3)     
LR Test                  22.321*** (df = 3)     
Score (Logrank) Test     25.183*** (df = 3)     
================================================
Note: se in parenthesis *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

However, as you can see, the stars are providing misleading inference, because t.stat = coef/se, however, in this case exponentiated coefs are being used as the numerator to compute the t stats and p values.

## Solution

Solution is to add parameters `p.auto = FALSE` and  `t.auto = FALSE` this will allows to use the original coefficients to compute the t.stats and p.values of the model.

```
stargazer(My.model, align=TRUE, 
          type="text", apply.coef = exp, p.auto = FALSE, 
          t.auto = FALSE, digits = 3)


================================================
                         Dependent variable:    
                     ---------------------------
                                stop            
------------------------------------------------
rx                             0.583*           
                               (0.200)          
                                                
size                            0.947           
                               (0.070)          
                                                
number                        1.213***          
                               (0.046)          
                                                
------------------------------------------------
Observations                     340            
R2                              0.064           
Max. Possible R2                0.971           
Log Likelihood                -588.104          
Wald Test                12.510*** (df = 3)     
LR Test                  22.321*** (df = 3)     
Score (Logrank) Test     25.183*** (df = 3)     
================================================
Note: se in parenthesis *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Moreover, to avoid confusion with your reader, you may report t.stats or pvalues instead of standard errors.

```
stargazer(My.model, align=TRUE, 
          type="text", apply.coef = exp, p.auto = FALSE, 
          t.auto = FALSE, digits = 3, report=('vc*p'))

================================================
                         Dependent variable:    
                     ---------------------------
                                stop            
------------------------------------------------
rx                             0.583*           
                              p = 0.070         
                                                
size                            0.947           
                              p = 0.535         
                                                
number                        1.213***          
                              p = 0.005         
                                                
------------------------------------------------
Observations                     340            
R2                              0.064           
Max. Possible R2                0.971           
Log Likelihood                -588.104          
Wald Test                12.510*** (df = 3)     
LR Test                  22.321*** (df = 3)     
Score (Logrank) Test     25.183*** (df = 3)     
================================================
Note:                *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `apply.coef` argument of the `stargazer` as such:

```r
stargazer(model, apply.coef = exp)
```

Per the link in the following post, you will likely have to do something a bit more intricate for the standard errors.

[Odds ratios instead of logits in stargazer() LaTeX output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236560/odds-ratios-instead-of-logits-in-stargazer-latex-output)

```r
get.or.se <- function(model) {
  broom::tidy(model) %>%
    mutate(or = exp(estimate),
           var.diag = diag(vcov(model)),
           or.se = sqrt(or^2 * var.diag)) %>%
    select(or.se) %>% unlist %>% unname
}
```

(Code borrowed from link, may have to adjust a bit for `survival`)